# Is there a GCC extension for implict return values?

Tags: c++, gcc, android-ndk, undefined-behavior

I had, and have since corrected, something like the following code:

```
class SomeClass {
public:
    static int AdjustValue(float input);
    static int DoSomethingWithAdjustedValue(int adjustedInput);
    static int DoSomethingWithNormalValue(float input) {
        DoSomethingWithAdjustedValue(AdjustValue(input);}
};
```

So `DoSomethingWithNormalValue` is clearly missing a `return`, but GCC did not generate an error or a warning for it.  And places where I was calling `DoSomethingWithNormalValue` were getting the correct return code.  I can think of two explanations for this:

1. There is some extension in GCC that recognizes inline functions that are wrapping other functions and passes the return values along.
2. The return code was being passed along because of a lucky/unlucky manifestation of undefined behavior combined with a bug in GCC that prevented any error or warning.

Neither of these strike me as being likely.  What is going on here?

Comment: Increase you warning level. It will warn you.

Comment: What is "the correct return code" when you are missing a `return` statement?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try:

```
> g++ xa1.cpp -Wall
xa1.cpp: In static member function ‘static int SomeClass::DoSomethingWithNormalValue(float)’:
xa1.cpp:8: warning: no return statement in function returning non-void
xa1.cpp:8: warning: control reaches end of non-void function
```

> The return code was being passed along because of a lucky/unlucky manifestation of undefined behavior combined with a bug in GCC that prevented any error or warning.

I think you will find this is what happens.
Technically it is undefined behavior.

Comment: If this is on x86, he is probably reading the old value of `eax` which would luckily hold the return code of the previous function if not overwritten.

Comment: That's the darndest thing, I could have sworn I had seen the "control reaches end of non-void function" pop up before.  But I just double checked my build settings and you're right.  Doh!

Answer (score 4):

C++ does not require a diagnostic for this but it is undefined behavior.

The reason you are getting the correct value is because the `DoSomethingWithAdjustedValue` places its return value where return values go, and then `DoSomethingWithNormalValue` isn't messing with any return values, so anything that looks for a return value after they call `DoSomethingWithNormalValue` will see the value returned by `DoSomethingWithAdjustedValue`.